# How to run commands in CI without being prompt for password

Tags: linux, unix, gitlab-ci, rhel

I want to include following commands in different stages of gitlab CI.

```
...
  script: |
    ssh -t ${SOME_USER}@${REMOTE_HOST} '([ -f "${FILE_PATH}/someFile.yaml" ] && cp -v "${FILE_PATH}/someFile.yaml" ${FILE_PATH}/someFile_yaml_$CI_COMMIT_TIMESTAMP.txt)'
...
  script: scp -v ${TF_ROOT}${LOCAL_FILE_PATH} ${SOME_USER}@${REMOTE_HOST}:${FILE_PATH}/
...
  script: ssh -t ${SOME_USER}@${REMOTE_HOST} sudo chown -cv runner:runner ${FILE_PATH}/someFile.yaml
...
  script: ssh -t ${SOME_USER}@${REMOTE_HOST} sudo systemctl restart some-service
...
```

Issue is when I execute this command individually manually, I have to provide password due to these being remote commands `ssh` and some require `sudo` and this approach wouldn’t work in a non-interactive mode such CI execution.

So how can I execute these commands in Gitlab CI without password prompts?

Comment: So what do you do to run ssh without a password? What do you do to run sudo without a password? It's exactly the same in gitlab-ci. And you run sudo on the remote, so you have to configure it on the remote. `ssh -t` do you really need a terminal? and https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/ssh_keys/

Answer (score 0):

As per your question what I understand is you just want to pass the password to run the command.

we have to different approach to solve this thing first you can use sshpass command along with all the commands if your ssh user has password sudo.

Have mentioned  some commands below for reference:

```
sshpass -p 'password' scp file.tar.gz root@xxx.xxx.xxx.194:/file/location
sshpass -p 'password' ssh user@ip command
```

and

another way you can create a passwordless sudo user to run the command and use pem key that would be more secure and much better.

you can search over internet for making user passwordless along with sudo permission

i hope this solve your issue

Answer (score 0):

Why not use `cron`? You can run your scripts as root without ever asking for a password.

You could do something like the following as root:

`crontab -e`, then:

(every 45 minutes)

```
*/45 * * * * /path/to/script1
```

(every 25 minutes, and so on)

```
*/25 * * * * /path/to/script2
```

etc, etc

Comment: The first `cron` record will not run every 45 minutes, but will run at 0 and 45 minute every hour. Same for 25 will run at 0, 25 and minute every hour

Comment: Yes, this is correct, but it will also run as I stated, every 45 minutes.